# Calculation of supply current in stepping motor driven using chopping driver

Tags: current, stepper-motor

I'm using STK 672-330 to drive a unipolar 2 phase stepping motor. The situation can be seen roughly in the circuit diagram below.
[image: example circuit diagram]

I set Vref so that the peak phase current becomes 1.2 A. 
When I measured the current in the phase A (blue arrow), i confirmed that it correctly peaked at 1.2A . But then I measured the current from 24V (red arrow) it looks more like DC 400 mA ish.

I did a few research and I found out that according to this [source](http://www.njr.com/semicon/PDF/application_notes/Drive_circuit_basics_APP_E.pdf) (around last page) supply current is calculated using this formula:

Isupply = IM · ( VM ⁄ Vsupply )

where IM is motor winding phase current, VM is motor winding voltage.

In my situation:
Vsupply= 24V, IM = 1.2A, VM = 3.6V (winding resistance is around 3 Ohms)
so it gives me Isupply = 180 mA for each phase. Which gives a total 0f 360 mA.
This result more or less agrees with my measurement.

But why does this equation holds? I find it strange we need to divide with Vsupply. If the current flowing in the phase peaks at 1.2A, why there is no such peak appear in the 24 V line? Where does the current come from and go to?

I have a hunch this has something to do with the PWM chopping by the FETs inside the driver IC. But I can't find satisfactory explanation for the continuity of current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, this is 'something to do with the chopping'.

Look up how a Buck DC to DC step down converter works. The inductance of the stepper motor acts as the inductor in a buck converter, while its resistance acts as the load resistance.

With the driver acting as a loss-less step-down buck converter, the power supply only needs to supply enough *power* to meet the power losses in the load. As the voltage is high, the current can be low.

Comment: Thank you for your response Neil. I looked up Buck Converters and found this [diagram] (http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/power-management/switching-mode-power-supply/smps-buck-switching-regulator-concept-05.gif). It shows that the input current enters the circuit as pulses. I see now that total power of the input pulses equals the DC output of the circuit. But how come I can't see the input pulse waveform? From this explanation I'm sure it peaks at 1.2 A also.

Comment: The 1.2A is delivered from time to time by the 100uF cap, which charges steadily at 400mA from the supply.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I missed the capacitor existence. Thanks a lot for the clue. It helped a lot.

Comment: How does this change when the motor is running and back EMF is present? the back-EMF adds to the coils R*I and therefore it will make the chopper increase the duty cycle to keep the specified current. As the duty increases, for a given current circulating, also will also the supply current increase?

Comment: If the motor is running, it's delivering power to a load. The back EMF increases the voltage that needs to be applied to the motor above that given by IR, which means for the same current, more power is being delivered to the motor. Therefore more power must be taken from the supply, which will have to increase its current output. The chopper will have to increase its duty cycle in line with the new input/output voltage ratio.